# The complexity of a variant algorithm for the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

What is the algorithm's complexity for a variant of the TSP problem where every node must be visited *at least once*, meaning that a node can be visited more than once? (The cycle starts from a specific node and, after passing all nodes (at least once) returns to the start node)

In the below link, I found a relevant algorithm, but its complexity is not given.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028657/find-the-shortest-cycle-in-a-positive-weighted-directed-graph-passing-through-on/75032146?noredirect=1#comment132525164_75032146

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the algorithm from the mentioned stackoverflow post (presented without a proof of correctness)

```
* remove nodes and associated edges that are not in S
# a factor of N
* Loop N over nodes
   # A term O(N * log(N))
   * Construct a spanning tree for the graph starting at N
   # A term O(N)
   * Connect leaf nodes of spanning tree
   # A factor of N
   * LOOP P over leaves of spanning tree
        * Mark P visited
        * set v = P
        # Here every iteration at one node is visited
        # so Another factor of N
        * While nodes remain unvisited
            * Set w to connected unvisited node nearest to v
            * IF w does not exist 
                # Without precomputation, this gives another O(N) term
                * Set w to nearest reachable node on spanning tree
                * Increment visits to nodes on path between v and W, excluding v and w
            * Mark w visited
            * Set v to w
        * Set L to length of path found
        * IF L < bestL
           * Set bestL = L
           * Set bestPath to current path
        * IF bestL == number of nodes - 1 break out of all loops
# O(N) term
* Find shortest path from end of bestPath back to beginning
```

Taking into account the operations commented on the algorithm the complexity is $O(N^2 log(N) + N + N^4)$ that can be simplified as $O(N^4)$.

### A correct algorithm

An algorithm easy to prove correct is

```
# A O(N^3) term
* Construct a graph G' with so that every pair u,v 
* is connected by a edge of cost equal to the best 
* path between u,v, in G
# A N! term
* Solve the TSP on G'
```

And has complexity $O(N^3 + N!)$, this makes me suspicious about the previous algorithm, is it providing a faster algorithm for TSP problem on fully connected graphs?

## Proof

By construction, if G' has an edge (u,v), the shortest path in G is the cost of the edge (u,v). If w is in the shortest path connecting u to v, G' also have edges (u,w) and (w,v).

So G' gives a way to hide the complexity of shortcuts.

The minimum cost trip G' is $u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_N$, has the minimum cost achievable for a trip passing through $u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_N$ in G. The solution the TSP G' is the minimum cost trip considering all the permutations of the vertices. Any trip visiting all the vertices of G' will have cost higher than at least one subsequence that gives the permutation of all the vertices of G. It follows that the minimum achievable cost of a trip visiting all the vertices in G is the cost of the optimal TSP solution in G'.

Comment: I am also suspicious about the algorithm provided on that link, as it can solve the TSP polynomially, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a reference that answers my question? Unfortunately, I could not understand your algorithm. Do you know any paper that explains how to solve the TSP where the nodes can be visited at least once?

Comment: I don't have any reference for that. I attempted to a proof, please check and let me know if you find any flaw.

Comment: TSP where the nodes can be visited at least once is equivalent to metric TSP (by exactly the $G$ to $G'$ transformation, which results in edge costs that satisfy the triangle inequality). This is still known to be NP-hard. The polynomial algorithm is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: Could you please help me what is the algorithm's complexity for solving my problem in terms of the graph order?

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: Given that we start from a specific node, is the complexity of my problem yet NP-hard?

Comment: For a cycle that passes through all nodes, it is irrelevant which node we consider "the start"!

Comment: Misha Lavrov: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate more on the complexity of the algorithm? You said that my problem is equivalent to metric TSP, so may I ask you what is the computational complexity of an exact algorithm for my problem?